# Running total wih constant numbers T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data looks like this

```
MILEAGE January February    ........December
   0       0        0   
   2       0.066    0.052
   3       0.081    0
   5       0        0.062
   6       0.080    0   .........
 813       0        0  and so on
```

I want the data to look like this

```
Mileage      January   February ..... December
  0         (Total of Mileage less and equal to zero for each month)
  2000       Total of Mileage upto 2000 for each month
  4000       Total of Mileage upto 4000 for each month
  6000       Total of Mileage upto 6000 for each month 
  8000       and so on....
  10000
  12000
  14000
  2 thousand increment up till 
  50000
```

Thank you very much for your help. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and not sure how to achieve this

Comment: Please clarify.  Is the value "MILEAGE" (in the first table) what's compared to your "upper bound" in the second table?  Like if MILEAGE=813 it is included in the totals for <=2000, but not for the row of totals <= 0?

Comment: Basically Mileage should have the constant values as defined in the second table. Mileage is raw data (in first table) that we receive from clients like (Ford, Gm etc) . Mileage will be included in 2000 and rest of the values up till 50000. It is running total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to make the table that lists the values on the fly as I show below.  HOWEVER, you would only want to do this if it was an ad-hoc once in a while thing.  If you are going to do it often (say every month) just make the table like you would make any other table and then you can add an index and join to it.

> The most common way thing to do is to have a counting table 0, 1, 2, 3 etc up to some large number.  Then you could get your result with `SELECT val*2000 FROM counting_table WHERE val*2000 >= 5000`.  This counting table can be reused for many similar cases but is general purpose.

```
WITH mile_table as
(
  -- use recursive cte to make a table with number 0 - 50000 by 2000
  SELECT 0 as milage

  UNION ALL

  SELECT mile_table.milage+2000
  FROM mile_table
  WHERE mile_table.milage+2000 <= 50000
)
SELECT mile_table.milage,
       sum(a.January) as January,
       sum(a.February) as February,
       --- ....
       sum(a.December) as December,
FROM mile_table 
JOIN your_table a ON a.milage >= mile_table.milage
GROUP BY mile_Table.milage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out something like this:

```
DECLARE @i as INT = -2000

CREATE TABLE #T 
(
  MileageFrom INT, 
  MileageTo INT
)

WHILE (@i <=50000)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #T 
    values(@i, @i+2000)

  SET @i= @i+2000
END

SELECT 
  A.MileageTo, 
  SUM(January) as january, 
  SUM(Feburary) as Feb ....,
  SUM(DEC) as DEC
FROM YourTable A 
JOIN #T B ON A.Mileage BETWEEN B.MileageFrom and B.MileageTo
```

You need to just tweak a bit the MileageFrom value to include all the values less than -2000

Comment: Why don't you indent your code?  Also, never a good idea to use a loop in SQL -- SQL is about sets not loops.

Comment: Thanks @Hogan for valuable suggestion on indenting the code.. regarding looping.. I believe your example is also having loop in the format of recursive CTE.. maby be yours one is better way of getting desired output. :)

Comment: then you believe wrong, a recursive CTE is not a loop.  You can tell because you have a `WHILE` keyword -- which is how you create a loop in SQL.

Comment: Thank you for both solutions. they both worked but I choose CTE as it was better fit to my needs.